# How to handle NA values when tokenizing the contents of a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have a pandas dataframe and I am trying to tokenize the contents of each row.

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk as nk
from nltk import word_tokenize

TextData = pd.read_csv('TextData.csv')
TextData['tokenized_summary'] = TextData.apply(lambda row: nk.word_tokenize(row['Summary']), axis=1)
```

When I run it, I get an error at line 67,

```
TypeError: ('expected string or buffer', u'occurred at index 67')
```

Which I think I am getting because the value for 'Summary' at iloc[67] is an NA value.

```
TextData.Summary.iloc[67]

Out[45]: nan
```

Assuming it is the na value which is causing this, is there a way to tell word_tokenize or pandas to ignore the NA values whenever it comes across them?

Else, what else might be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fillna()` to replace NaN with a specified value:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk as nk
from nltk import word_tokenize

TextData = pd.read_csv('TextData.csv')
TextData.fillna('some value') # or just: TextData['Summary'].fillna('some value')
TextData['tokenized_summary'] = TextData.apply(lambda row: nk.word_tokenize(row['Summary']), axis=1)
```

---

#### Previous Answer

You can simply "eliminate" the records where that value is null:

```
TextData = TextData[TextData['tokenized_summary'].notnull()]
```

Making the final product look like:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk as nk
from nltk import word_tokenize

TextData = pd.read_csv('TextData.csv')
TextData = TextData[TextData['tokenized_summary'].notnull()]
TextData['tokenized_summary'] = TextData.apply(lambda row: nk.word_tokenize(row['Summary']), axis=1)
```

Comment: I want to keep those records, since other columns in the df contain relevant information.

Comment: OK. Modified the lambda to return None. Try that out.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, even though TextData.Summary.iloc[67] returns *nan*. Am I missing something?